# Is there a best Rampage floor to farm moonbow gems?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

Is there a floor that has the best drop rates or easiest to kill in order to get moonbow gems easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**13-14** are particularly easy to do quickly and the mobs don’t hit very hard